# Chemfig doesn't work since MiKTeX update

Tags: miktex, chemfig

Since I've updated all packages in MiKTeX, the chemfig-package doesn't work anymore. When I run the document in Texmaker, I get the errors "Undefined control sequence. \defKV", "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}." and many different "Illegal parameter number in definition of \CF_atomstyle" "...\CF_chemfigstyle" etc..

Minumum example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
Any text using chemical formulas e.g. propane (\chemfig{H_3C-[:30,2]-[:-30,2]CH_3}).
\end{document}
```

The pdf then looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: works ok for me. Did you update in user *and* admin mode?

Comment: Yes, I updated both. Sadly, it doesn't work.

Comment: then show the complete log-file of your example.

Comment: Sorry for the maybe dumb question, but how can I upload the log-file?